# LaTeX delete newlines

Tags: arabic

I have this LaTeX code and it inserts a newline before and after the Arabic text. I want it intext, how so?

```
\documentclass[11pt,arabtex]{article}
\usepackage{conf}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\title{maintitle}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract body. I want to insert Arabic here like 
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
عربي
\end{arabtext}
\end{abstract}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ArabTex documentation](http://baobab.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/arabtex/doc/arabdoc.pdf) 
the `arabtex` environment (as in `\begin{arabtext}`) starts a new paragraph.

For inline I think you need:

```
This is the abstract body. I want to insert Arabic here like 
\setcode{utf8}<عربي> or \<salAm>
```

Comment: Yes, \setcode{utf8}\<عربي> works pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that *most* environments have this behavior written in.